# How to work ie comment tags

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I've used something which isn't working at IE7. That's why, I wanted to write some specific css for ie7 and lower only. That's why, I wrote IE comments tag inside html  tag. But, it's not working. I wrote at first:

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sites/css/ie7-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

But, it's not working! I haven't ie7. I had to check via developers tool of IE. I thought, at developers tool, comment tag doesn't work. That's why, for checking I wrote comment tag for all IE such as:

```
<!--[if IE]>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sites/css/all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

But, still it's not working!! I don't understand why it's happened. [This is the website.](http://abidhasan.zxq.net/aiub-cs/index-1.html) I need to replace navigation for IE 7. the navigation is defined at my main stylesheet such as:

```
.modern-menu {
   display: block;
}
```

I need to remove this at ie so that I wrote at my ie specific styleshhet such as:

```
.modern-menu {
   display: none;
}
```

some HTML CODE of the websites:

```
<ul class="modern-menu>
<li>abcd</li>
<li>abcd</li>
<li>abcd</li>
<li>abcd</li>
</ul>
```

**style.css:**

```
.modern-menu {
    width: 920px;
    height: 40px;
    width:99%;
    font-family: 'SourceSansProRegular',Arial,Helvetica,"Nimbus Sans L",sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    float:left;
    font-weight: normal;
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    margin-top:0px;
    display: block;
}
```

**all-ie-only.css:**

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
    background-color: #0099FF;
}
.modern-menu {
    display: none;
}
.nav {
    display: block;
}
```

Can you please tell me Why this comments tag not working?

Comment: Repetition doesn't really help unless its specific.

Answer (score 1):

In the MS IE developer tools, you can set the browser and document version. Maybe you have just set the browser version.

> In Internet Explorer 10 HTML conditional comments are not supported when the page is in standards mode.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment

Make sure that both buttons above the developer tools window display IE 10 to get a similar result as in the original MS IE 7. The only way to really test what happens in IE 7 is to use an IE 7 (for example in a second [Windows test installation inside a virtual machine](http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools))

Comment: I've written 
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sites/css/ie7-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
at first and then for testing, I replaced with this:
<!--[if IE]>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sites/css/all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
I don't understand what's the wrong with that I mean how do I write the document version for this?

Comment: @user1896653 `<!--[if IE]>` is ignored by IE 10+ as they don't support conditional comments anymore. If the document mode still is set to IE 10 there simply are no conditional comments…